# Spring Boot Test using Neo4j embedded database with JDBC Bolt driver

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

Is it possible to connect to an embedded Neo4j database the same way you would do with an H2 in-memory database to mock an Oracle database?

I've tried to do this:

```
final BoltConnector boltConnector = new BoltConnector("bolt");
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
        .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_PATH)
        .setConfig(boltConnector.type, BOLT.name())
        .setConfig(boltConnector.enabled, TRUE)
        .setConfig(boltConnector.listen_address, listenAddress("127.0.0.1", 7688))
        .setConfig(boltConnector.encryption_level, DISABLED.name())
        .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.auth_enabled, FALSE)
        .newGraphDatabase();
```

And then make a request using the JDBC Bolt driver with the following spring.datasource configuration:

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.neo4j.jdbc.bolt.BoltDriver
    url: jdbc:neo4j:bolt://127.0.0.1:7688/?nossl
```

But I always get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:7688, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
```

Of course the embedded database works when I use the `graphDb` instance and execute requests against it. But I want my application to connect to the embedded database as it does when connecting to a remote Neo4j database.
This is for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally RTFM...
I had the following dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I found this: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-java-embedded-bolt
The documentation is a bit outdated because it uses deprecated configuration. But they explain this:

> The Neo4j Browser and the official Neo4j Drivers use the Bolt database
>   protocol to communicate with Neo4j. By default, Neo4j Embedded does
>   not expose a Bolt connector, but you can enable one. Doing so allows
>   you to connect the services Neo4j Browser to your embedded instance.

And they make clear the correct dependency to use is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-bolt</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```